# Jenkins pipeline, groovy map array as choises

Tags: jenkins, groovy

How can I pass the array variable into the global variable in groovy?
It works perfectly without if-else.

```
choiceArray = []
if (appName == 'ms'){
                        ['78', '99', '10'].each {
                                        "${choiceArray}" << it
                        }
}
else if (appName == 'ms2'){
                        ['12', '34', '56'].each {
                                        "${choiceArray}" << it
                        }
}

  pipeline {
    parameters {
      string (name: 'Branch', defaultValue: 'master', description: 'Select Branch')
      choice(name: 'Environment', choices: choiceArray, description: 'Choose Environment')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(...){
   choiceArray.addAll(['78', '99', '10'])
}
```

Comment: Thanks daggett, but unfortunately it didn't work, because the choiceArray still empty :/

Comment: So maybe your `if` is incorrect?

Comment: How do you mean?

Current setup:

```
choiceArray = []
if(appName == 'ms'){
              choiceArray.addAll(['78', '99', '10'])
}
else if(appName == 'ms2'){
              choiceArray.addAll(['78', '99', '10'])
}
```

Comment: maybe `appName` never get value `ms` and `ms2`?

Comment: Thanks it solved my problem, I found a typo in my appName string :)